# How to Connect 2 Data Extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I'm back for more learning!

Thanks to @adamspriggs blog for all the different examples and resources. However, I'm not fully sure, if I'm understanding how to use 2 different DEs properly? I have attempted to write some codes here. To make thing a little be more complicated one of the DE is sendable and the other DE has 12 products with 3 columns (product number, product name, rank). I'm trying to create a loop for those 12 items that I have ranked 1-12. And I'm trying to show only 4 products in the email based on those 12 items.

```
    %%[
 var @rowCount, @row, @i, @lookup
 var @memid
 set @memid= AttributeValue("EmailAddress")

 if not empty(@memid) then 
 set @lookup = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionNameSendable1", "EmailAdress" @memid)
 set @rowCount = rowcount(@lookup)
endif 
 for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      set @row = rows(@lookup,@i)
      set @memid = Field(row, "EmailAddress")

   then
     if not empty(@ProductNumber) then
     var @lookup2,@rowCount, @row, @i, @lookup
     var @Pimage, @Pname, @Purl, @ProductNumber
     set @ProductNumber= AttributeValue("ProductNumber")
    endif

 set @lookup2 = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName2", 12, "rank asc", "ProductNumber" @ProductNumber) 
 set @rowCount = rowcount(@lookup2) > = 1 then

 for @i = 1 to @rowCount(@lookup2) do 
      set @row = rows(@lookup2, @i)  
   IF @i == 1 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ELSEIF @i == 2 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ELSEIF @i == 3 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ELSEIF @i == 4 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ELSEIF @i == 5 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ELSEIF @i == 6 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ELSEIF @i == 7 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ELSEIF @i == 8 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ELSEIF @i == 9 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ELSEIF @i == 10 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL") 
   ELSEIF @i == 11 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL") 
   ELSEIF @i == 12 THEN
      set @Pimage = Field(@row, "ProductImageURL")
      set @Pname = Field(@row, "ProductName")
      set @Purl = Field(@row, "ProductURL")
   ENDIF

]%%

%%[ if not empty(@banner) or not empty(@promocode) or not empty (@ahref) then ]%%

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
   <tr>

 %%[ if not empty(@Pname) then ]%%

      <td>%%=v(@Pname)</td>

       %%[ endif ]%%

       %%[ if not empty(@Pimage) and not empty (@PruductURL) then ]%%

       <td><img src="%%=v(@Pimage)=%%"><a href="%%=v(@ProductURL)=%%"></a></td>

      %%[ endif ]%%

   </tr>
    <tr>

 %%[ if not empty(@Pname) then ]%%

      <td>%%=v(@Pname)</td>

       %%[ endif ]%%

       %%[ if not empty(@Pimage) and not empty (@PruductURL) then ]%%

       <td><img src="%%=v(@Pimage)=%%"><a href="%%=v(@ProductURL)=%%"></a></td>

      %%[ endif ]%%

   </tr>
    <tr>

 %%[ if not empty(@Pname) then ]%%

      <td>%%=v(@Pname)</td>

       %%[ endif ]%%

       %%[ if not empty(@Pimage) and not empty (@PruductURL) then ]%%

       <td><img src="%%=v(@Pimage)=%%"><a href="%%=v(@ProductURL)=%%"></a></td>

      %%[ endif ]%%

   </tr>
    <tr>

 %%[ if not empty(@Pname) then ]%%

      <td>%%=v(@Pname)</td>

       %%[ endif ]%%

       %%[ if not empty(@Pimage) and not empty (@PruductURL) then ]%%

       <td><img src="%%=v(@Pimage)=%%"><a href="%%=v(@ProductURL)=%%"></a></td>

      %%[ endif ]%%

   </tr>
</table>
%%[ endif ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

<br>row not found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the research I find:

- you can't select two DE and write an AMPscript on it. You need to use a Query Activity to nest your second DE. It will create a new set of rows from your primary DE. After you will write an AMPscript to look up multiple column values from multiple ordered rows.

Process:

- Used Email Studio or Journey Builder to create your [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/use_the_sql_query_activity/)(depend on your campaign)
- Write an AMPscript Lookup() or LookupOrderRows()

Please correct me if I have missed a step or my answer is wrong.